# active menu in post page

Tags: menus

I am showing a wp menu with the following function:

```
<?php
                    wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'theme_location'    => 'primary', 
                            'container'         => false,
                            'depth'             => 2,
                        ) 
                    );
                    ?>
```

My menu has only pages and no posts or categories. One of my page is showing posts. If i click one of the posts, I go to that post page. But problem is that, then I cant get the active menu. It make sense because it is in post page now. but how can i achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

The below filter adds your class based on title, you could also do this by post ID if you'd like: `$item->object_id == 123`

```
function wp_nav_parent_class( $classes, $item ) {

    if( is_singular('post') && $item->title == "Your Menu Item Title Here" )
        array_push($classes, 'current_page_parent');

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'wp_nav_parent_class', 10, 2);
```

If `is_singular('post')` does not work try `is_single()`, but it should work. Just replace the conditional string with the menu item title of your choice.